# Как сформировать список id из списка словарей записей из БД?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jinja2

Запрос возвращает из БД список из словарей с данными записей.

```
result = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'Name 1', 'description': 'desc one...'},
          {'id': 2, 'name': 'Name 2', 'description': 'desc two...'},
          {'id': 3, 'name': 'Name 3', 'description': 'desc three...'}]
```

Как сформировать список айдишкиов для передачи в html?

Я пытаюсь так:

```
for i in result:
    return render_template("dashboard.html",
                                   user=user,
                                   check_inner=i)
```

При таком варианте check_inner передает в html не список а только первый элемент списка.
А требуется передать список айдишников для дальнейшей обработки в jinja2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, возможно, так:

```py
return render_template("dashboard.html",
                                   user=user,
                                   check_inner=[row['id'] for row in result])
```

Comment: Работает!!! Ура! Большое Спасибо!!!